# links don't work within <ul> or <ol> tags

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, hyperlinks

A minor bug: if you use <ul> or <ol> tags instead of using Markdown notation for creating lists, links don't work. For example, the input

```
<ul>
<li> [google](http://google.com) </li>
</ul>

- [google](http://google.com)

<ol>
<li> [google](http://google.com) </li>
</ol>

1. [google](http://google.com)
```

produces

- [google](http://google.com)

- [google](http://google.com)

1. [google](http://google.com)

1. [google](http://google.com)

Comment: One thing: you're not actually closing your <li> elements.

Comment: @cletus: fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Minor nitpick: Closing `<li>` tags is actually optional in HTML: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#h-10.2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [Markdown syntax page](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax):

> Note that Markdown formatting syntax is not processed within block-level HTML tags. E.g., you can’t use Markdown-style *emphasis* inside an HTML block.

`<ul>` is a block level HTML tag, so according to the spec it your example behaves correctly.

However, there appears to be an exception to this in SO markdown to handle simple formatting such as italics and bold within HTML:

- **markdown-bold in a markdown bullet**

**markdown-bold in HTML bullet**

Answer (score 4):

You'll have to do this:

```
<ul>
<li> <a href="http://google.com">google</a> </li>
</ul>

- [google](http://google.com)

<ol>
<li> <a href="http://google.com">google</a> </li>
</ol>

1. [google](http://google.com)
```

Getting this

> - [google](http://google.com)
>
> - [google](http://google.com)
>
> 1. [google](http://google.com)
>
> 1. [google](http://google.com)

Just don't mix both styles.

Answer (score 2):

That's how markdown works.  If you start talking HTML, it figures that it can't possibly know enough about what you're doing to try and make guesses at what your meaning is, so it just dumps everything through literally.